# Node js error handler issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, middleware

The general topic of this ticket is node js middleware and error handlers

When a user accesses a link like `site.com/user/username`, I want to print a message if a user with the specified username exists.

I have written 2 middleware functions to implement that: the first one is `users` and the 2nd one is `errorHandler`.

But for some reason the whole program doesn't work. Please tell me where I went wrong.
Here's the code:

```js
let connect = require('connect');
let port = 3000;

let api = connect()
 .use(users)
 .use(errorHandler)
 .listen(port);

var db = {
 users: [
  { name: 'tobi' },
  { name: 'loki' },
  { name: 'jane' }
 ]
};

function users(req, res, next) {
 var match = req.url.match(/^\/user\/(.+)/)
 if (match) {
  var user = db.users[match[1]];
  if (user) {
   res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
   res.end(JSON.stringify(user));
  } else {
   var err = new Error('User not found');
   err.notFound = true;
   next(err);
  }
 } else {
  next();
 }
}


function errorHandler(err, req, res, next) {
 console.error(err.stack);
 res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
 if (err.notFound) {
  res.statusCode = 404;
  res.end(JSON.stringify({ error: err.message }));
 } else {
  res.statusCode = 500;
  res.end(JSON.stringify({ error: 'Internal Server Error' }));
 }
}
```

Comment: `db.users[match[1]]` <<-- You can't index into an array of objects like this.  You need loop though the array for a user where `user.name === match[1]`

Comment: To be exact, it always shows `User not found`

Comment: exactly, db.users[match[1]] will aways return `undefined`.  You are not doing the lookup correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is looking for a solution in the wrong part of your db object. your code as written is looking for `db.users['toby']` when it should be looking for `db.users[0].name = 'toby'` I would recommend using the [array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method to search your array of names

```js
function users(req, res, next) {
  let match = req.url.match(/^\/user\/(.+)/)

  if (!match) { next() }

  let user = db.users.find(v => v.name === match);

  if (user === undefined) {
    let err = new Error('User not found')
    err.notFound = true;
    next(err);
  }

  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  res.end(JSON.stringify(user));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const users = [
  { name: 'tobi' },
  { name: 'loki' },
  { name: 'jane' }
];

findUser = userName => { for (let user of users) if (user.name === userName) return user; }

console.log(findUser('tobi'));
```